# How to restrict javascript embed to only work on certain domains

Tags: javascript, api, cross-domain

Google maps does it, so does Google reCaptcha - it verifies that the supplied API key is being used on an allowed domain. Can anyone point me at some resources that explain how this is done please?

More Detail:
I would like to supply users of my service with a javascript snippet that they can insert into their own website, e.g.:

```
<script src="https://example.com/api?key=1234341234"></script>
```

When the script runs, it needs to check that it is running inside a website on one of the allowed domains that my user has specified, exactly as Google Maps does - so as to prevent unauthorised users from 'stealing' an API key to use on their own site.

**EDIT:**

The script in question will then submit values to a server side API, so there could be an element of client & server validation in the solution. What we are trying to prevent is malicious/unauthorised users submitting to the server.

I've done some searching but not found anything particularly useful, so any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
if(window.location.href == *your website*) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: See my edit. This approach could easily be circumvented by saving the script and removing that check, then using the modified script.

Comment: since javascript is client-side, that's obv.

Comment: Please explain why this will work for the sake of future readers.

Comment: This will surely work, but as @Simon says, users may change that. That's normal since we're talking about js